# Significado de la metrica best_score

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estoy realizando una estimación de parámetros de distintas técnicas de machine learning como árbol de decisión, k vecino, para esto utilizo un gridsearch como el siguiente:

```
#GridSearch for tree

clf_t = GridSearchCV( DecisionTreeClassifier(), {
    'max_depth' : [11,19,21,25,27],
    'min_samples_split': [1170, 1200, 1211, 1231],
    'min_samples_leaf': [57,60,63,65,71] 
    
}, cv=10, return_train_score=False )
```

De este proceso me interesa las metricas de best_score y best_params que proporciona la libreria

La pregunta es que significado tiene la metrica best_score, he leido la documentación y no me queda claro

Alguno podría ayudarme a entender en profundidad este dato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> En el caso de: best_params_ retorna los mejores parámetros obtenidos en la búsqueda.

> En el caso de: best_score_ obtienes el promedio de la validación cruzada obtenida para tu métrica de error.

En este caso obtendrás dicho promedio como un valor referente de una métrica propia de la clasificación dado que empleas la instacia de DecisionTreeClassifier.